# Reading from URL - Java, C#, Android, Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, text-files

is it possible to read from a URL that is directed to a text file. e.g.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53441658/read.txt

Instead of giving a file path that is located on the computer, I want to give a path to a text file, via a url. Something like this;

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53441658/read.txt", true);
```

Comment: How come this is both a **java** and **C#** question?

Comment: because I am working on a project for different platform and in one I am using java and in the other C# and I need to read from a url in both languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Java (Android)**

```
 URL url = new URL("ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/index.html");
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   try {
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     in.close();
   }
 }
```

P.S. You must do this in separate thread like Async Task. [Read more on Android Official Documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)

**In Dot.Net C#**

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string s = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo fast reply, can I use this url https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53441658/read.txt

Comment: No, it is specific for java

Comment: For C# look for "WebClient" Class or "HttpClient".